# Most natural way of reading letters (in USA)

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech

I'm developing an IOS app that uses speech recognition. Since the state of the art does not provide good accuracy on recognizing single letters (random, not spelling).

I was thinking to use a set of words, one per alphabet letter, and recognize those words instead (it gives hugely improved accuracy).

In Italy, for instance, it is widely used a set of city names (for spelling purpose):

```
A - Ancona
B - Bari
C - Como
... and so on
```

My question is, an average person in USA, what set of words would use??

It is for instance the NATO alphabet? Or is there another set or sets (I could always work with a mix). The only thing I cannot do is to work with the complete English Corpus ;)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly do you want to recognize? There might be better solution, using alphabet is not an option either you input single letters or phonetic alphabet words.

Answer (score 2):

As a pilot I would recommend the standard phonetic alphabet:

- A - Alpha
- B - Bravo
- C - Charlie

etc.

So yes, the [NATO Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet).

Keep in mind though that the "average" person in the USA doesn't know this alphabet. But most would know what you meant if it's used though. The occasional time I've run into a non-pilot person trying to clarify a letter, people just make up a word that starts with the letter. There is no "standard" in the USA that non-pilots know.

Comment: Mmm so maybe the thing to do here is to add some common words to the mix and hope they say that one!